# Html minimize expand option missing

Tags: html, asp.net, web, intellisense

Suddenly I have no option to minimize or expand html code.

Aka the ability to do:

[image]

to this

[image]

Only css elements within "`<styles>`" has this ability. None of my other elements ("`<div>`" etc) has it anymore.

[image]

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Edit->Outling->Stop Outlining

Edit->Outlining-Start Automatic Outlining